# Ways to write a number as a sum

Tags: sum, combinations

I want to write for example number 10 all the possible ways as a sum of units 3, 4, ..., n-1 (not 2)
for example i can write 10 as

```
10=10(units)
10=7 + 1*3 or 
10=4 + 2*3 or
10=3 + 1*3 + 1*4 or
10=2 + 2*4 or ....
```

I dont care about the number of combinations!
I want the combinations!!! I mean an algoithm to output like this

```
un 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
-------------------
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
07 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
04 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
03 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
02 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0   etc
```

any response is welcomed!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. start with zero
2. try to add the largest possible number
3. store the result, if you arrive at the target sum
4. else if you ended with less than the target sum, go to (2)
5. else (if you ended with more than the target sum)

   1. undo the last adding step, try to add one less instead. If you don't have any more smaller numbers to try, undo one more addition in past
      if you run out of all possible additions, you already found all combinations and can exit.

Example:

```
target = 10
0
0 + 9 -> not there yet
0 + 9 + 9 -> too much, try something less
0 + 9 + 8 -> too much, try less
...
...
...
0 + 9 + 3 -> too much, cant try any less
0 + 8 -> not there yet
0 + 8 + 8 -> too much
...
...
...
0 + 8 + 3 -> too much, cant try any less
0 + 7 -> not there yet
0 + 7 + 7 -> too much
0 + 7 + 6 -> too much
...
...
...
0 + 7 + 3 -> thats it! save!
0 + 6 -> not yet
0 + 6 + 6 -> too much...
```

I hope you get the idea... :)
It will be much much faster, than trying all the possible combinations and selecting only the ones that sum to 10. This approach is called backtracking (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), because you try to go in some direction (adding the largest number), but when you fail (sum is too big), you track your progress back and then try something different.

You can then speed it up by trying the possibilities in more clever way (0 + 7 + 7 is too much by 4, so don't even try 0 + 7 + 6, but skip straight to 0 + 7 + 3).